# ARCGIS flex overlay floor plan png

Tags: apache-flex, image, overlay, arcgis

We have floor plans of a building in the DB in PNG format.
We am using arcGIS flex api. We want to build something like 
http://www.laudontech.com/officeplans/

How can we load my building floor plan onto the arcGIS flex map.

Please let me know.

Thanks,  Vish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to set up the image as a tiled/dynamic service on your ArcGIS server and use the Flex API to connect to it just like any other service.

Here is ESRI's samples page:
http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/flex/samples/index.html

Comment: Hi Bal,
I am very new to the GIS world. Please let me know the answers,

1. Do we need to setup our own ArcGIS server or an we use an existing one(free service)

2. All we need is to point to our building from a world map, zoom to the building view, where i should load the floorplan png.

Pl let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Vish -- you're better off heading to ESRI's website and asking on the forums there.  You can connect to any web accessible ArcGIS server and add map layers.  Your png has to be hosted as a service on an ArcGIS server, so if you don't do it yourself, somebody will have to do it for you.  Regardless, it will require an ArcGIS server.  But again, the ESRI forums will be a much bigger help.